# Calling pthread_detach for an already exited thread?

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *tfunc(void *data)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t t;

    pthread_create(&t, NULL, tfunc, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_detach(t);

    return 0;
}
```

See the MWE.
It works fine, but I am unsure if this is actually defined behavior. The man page of `pthread_detach` says nothing about calling it on exited threads.

Yes I know about creating threads with the detached attribute, but I am specifically curious about this situation. `pthread_join` has a mention on this case and I assume `pthread_detach` works just as fine, but I haven't found any official statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is perfectly legal, and does not invoke undefined behavior:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *tfunc(void *data)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t t;

    pthread_create(&t, NULL, tfunc, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_detach(t);

    return 0;
}
```

It's not really clearly stated, but the [POSIX documentation for `pthread_detach()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) is worded in such a way that it must be defined and correct to call `pthread_detach()` on a terminated thread:

> The `pthread_detach()` function shall indicate to the implementation
>   that storage for the thread thread can be reclaimed when that thread
>   terminates. If thread has not terminated, `pthread_detach()` shall not
>   cause it to terminate.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the thread
>   argument to `pthread_detach()` does not refer to a joinable thread.

First, note the statement "If thread has not terminated".  That implies that it must be safe to call `pthread_detach()` when the thread *has* terminated.

Second, note "The behavior is undefined if ... does not refer to a joinable thread."  In your posted code, the thread you created is clearly joinable - you didn't create it with a detached attribute, so you could call `pthread_join()` to retrieve its returned value.  So it's not undefined behavior.

Remember, there's no guaranteed way to ensure from thread A that thread B is still running when either `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` is called.  So either call has to be safe to call (once!) from any thread on any other thread.

Also, from the Rationale section of the POSIX documentation:

> **RATIONALE**
>
> The `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` functions should eventually
>   be called for every thread that is created so that storage associated
>   with the thread may be reclaimed.
>
> It has been suggested that a "detach" function is not necessary; the
>   detachstate thread creation attribute is sufficient, since a thread
>   need never be dynamically detached. However, need arises in at least
>   two cases:
>
> 1. In a cancellation handler for a `pthread_join()` it is nearly essential to have a `pthread_detach()` function in order to detach the
>      thread on which `pthread_join()` was waiting. Without it, it would be
>      necessary to have the handler do another `pthread_join()` to attempt
>      to detach the thread, which would both delay the cancellation
>      processing for an unbounded period and introduce a new call to
>      `pthread_join()`, which might itself need a cancellation handler. A
>      dynamic detach is nearly essential in this case.
> 2. In order to detach the "initial thread" (as may be desirable in processes that set up server threads).

Again, while not clearly stated, note the implied equivalence between `pthread_join()` and `pthread_detach()`.

Comment: I fully agree with the interpretations of this answer. It's more common to call `pthread_detach` (or with detachable attribute) from within the thread than from another thread (such as `pthread_detach(pthread_self())`). So the raised issue in the question isn't much of a practical concern.

Comment: I read POSIX the same way you do, especially in light of other pthreads docs, but would it have hurt them to be more explicit here?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added the "Rationale" section from POSIX.